# alignParentBottom In a Layout Inflate

Tags: java, android, layout

I have a `ListActivity` that I'm trying to inflate a `Button` from this layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_button"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/add_prop"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Using this code:

```
View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
ListView listView = getListView();

listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
listView.addFooterView(footer, null, false);
```

The problem is that since the list isn't so big that takes the entire screen (at least I think this is why) the button stays at the end of the list instead of sticking to the bottom because of the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` property. What should I do to make it stick at the bottom?

Comment: I don't think `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` has any effect inside LinearLayout. it only works for RelativeLayout.

Comment: Changed `footer.xml` to `RelativeLayout` and nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new layout file with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/add_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_button"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/add_prop"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout >
```

Then set it as content view of your `Activity` using [`setContentView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29)

Comment: But I'm using a `ListActivity` to generate the list, not a layout file. How do I populate a `ListView` on a layout file from Java?

Comment: If you use my layout, `ListActivity` will automatically use the ListView in the layout file - the one with the id `@android:id/list` - and not generate its own one.